# Memcached Object Too Large

Tags: memcached

In my `memcahced` configuration I have

```
 PORT="11211"                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 USER="memcached"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 MAXCONN="1024"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 MAXITEMSIZE=5M                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 CACHESIZE="12288"                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 LOGFILE="/var/log/memcached.log"                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 OPTIONS="-vv >> /var/log/memcached 2>&1"
```

This is also what I see when I run a `stats`

```
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
```

But when I try to write a big item

```
set test 0 60 5000000 asdas
SERVER_ERROR object too large for cache
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the problem is how you star memcached.
If you start with init.d based ssytem (like Centos6)
you have to check if the /etc/initd./memcached script start the daemon with 
the -I option.
In my case, the -I options was not set in the init script. So:

```
start () {
...
 daemon --pidfile ${pidfile} memcached -d -p $PORT -u $USER  -m $CACHESIZE -c -I $MAXITEMSIZE $MAXCONN -P ${pidfile} $OPTIONS
```

Similarly, if your system is based on systemd, like Centos7

```
[Service]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Type=simple                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/memcached                                                                                                                                                                                                 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/memcached -u $USER -p $PORT -I $MAXITEMSIZE -m  $CACHESIZE -c $MAXCONN $OPTIONS
```